# How to check my user id?

Tags: support, edits

I want to check how many questions/answers I have edited so far in Stackexchange site. I found the [answer link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35999/how-many-copy-editor-strunk-white-qualifying-edits-have-i-made). I dont know my userid But i gave my profile name its shown error message that **"Invalid column name"**

Help me to where i am wrong.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it when you go to your profile:

1. In the URL. Your profile link on Meta (note the user ID's differ per site) is https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/267002/prabhakaran, so your user ID is 267002.

   [image]
2. Also, in that profile page, you have a search bar showing `user:267002`.

   [image]